# Get parent value based on child's matching value in SQL query

Tags: sql, oracle

I need a parent table value from select query where parent's child value either of few or all are in child's table.

Let me give you an example.

Category Parent Table

```
CatId PrdId
-----------
Cat1  prd1
Cat1  prd2
Cat1  prd3
Cat2  prd4
Cat2  prd5
Cat2  prd6
```

Product Child Table

```
PrdId
-----
prd1
prd2
prd3
prd4
prd5
```

I am using oracle sqldevloper. See below query,

```
Select Category.CatId 
from Category cat 
  left join Product prd ON cat.PrdId = prd.PrdId
```

This query gives me Cat1,Cat2 results but it should get only Cat1 because Cat2 prd6 value is not available in Product table.

Edit: Can we achieve this without using group by and count?

Comment: Use an inner join instead of an outer join

Answer (score 1):

What about this solution?

```
select distinct catid from category where catid not in (
select distinct c.catid from category c left join product p on (c.prdid = p.prdid) where p.prdid is null);
```

You basically select all the products and assign them a relevant category. Those which don't have a category are assigned NULL. Then you select only those categories, which have NULL and remove such list of categories from another select containing all the categories.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `GROUP BY` and `HAVING` as following:

> ```
> SQL> WITH CATEGORY AS (
>   2      SELECT 'Cat1' CATID, 'prd1' PRDID FROM DUAL UNION ALL
>   3      SELECT 'Cat1' CATID, 'prd2' PRDID FROM DUAL UNION ALL
>   4      SELECT 'Cat1' CATID, 'prd3' PRDID FROM DUAL UNION ALL
>   5      SELECT 'Cat2' CATID, 'prd4' PRDID FROM DUAL UNION ALL
>   6      SELECT 'Cat2' CATID, 'prd5' PRDID FROM DUAL UNION ALL
>   7      SELECT 'Cat2' CATID, 'prd6' PRDID FROM DUAL
>   8  ), PRODUCT AS (
>   9      SELECT 'prd1' PRDID FROM DUAL UNION ALL
>  10      SELECT 'prd2' PRDID FROM DUAL UNION ALL
>  11      SELECT 'prd3' PRDID FROM DUAL UNION ALL
>  12      SELECT 'prd4' PRDID FROM DUAL UNION ALL
>  13      SELECT 'prd5' PRDID FROM DUAL
>  14  ) -- Your actual solution starts from here
>  15  SELECT CAT.CATID
>  16  FROM CATEGORY CAT LEFT JOIN PRODUCT P ON CAT.PRDID = P.PRDID
>  17  GROUP BY CAT.CATID
>  18  HAVING COUNT(CASE WHEN P.PRDID IS NULL THEN 1 END) = 0;
>
> CATI
> ----
> Cat1
>
> SQL>
> ```

Cheers!!

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is called *[relational division](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relational_algebra#Division_(%C3%B7))*. It is operation based on relational algebra, to some extent it can be considered as inverse to cartesian product. Unfortunately it has no direct support in SQL standard. You can emulate it by two `not exist`s or by `group by + having count`.

[This is IMHO the best article on this topic.](https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/sql/t-sql-programming/divided-we-stand-the-sql-of-relational-division/) You can easily learn from it how to apply both ways onto your example.